# Sorting dictionary by value in python under multiple constraints

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

Consider the dictionary below: Let's call it `hmap`
This is a dictionary where they key is of type `int` and the values are `tuples`

```
{1: (80, 40, 120), 2: (60, 20, 80), 3: (80, 50, 130), 4: (60, 90, 150), 5: (70, 90, 160), 6: (70, 80, 150)}
```

To sort the dictionary by value in `reverse` order; something like the following can be done.
For example:

```
mm = {k:v for k, v in sorted(hmap.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)}
```

The sorted O/P is as follows:

```
{3: (80, 50, 130), 1: (80, 40, 120), 5: (70, 90, 160), 6: (70, 80, 150), 4: (60, 90, 150), 2: (60, 20, 80)}
```

Since I am sorting the `dict` by value, it defaults to sorting by the first value in the `tuple`.

Please consider the following scenario's:

1. What's the best approach to sorting the dict by second (or) third value in the tuple?
2. Likewise, what if I would like to sort by the second value in the tuple; yet if there is a tie, I would like to sort them in the ascending order of the `key` value?

In scenario 2, Consider `hmap` to be:

```
{1: (80, 40, 120), 2: (60, 20, 80), 3: (80, 50, 130)}
```

Here if we sort this by first value of the tuple in `reverse`; there would be a tie; since `80` is found in both key `1` and key `3`.

What's the best way to sort by the first value in the `tuple`, while giving ascending order of priority to the `key` value incase of a tie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tell `key` to ignore the first element using slicing to create a new tuple without the first element:

   ```py
   dict(sorted(hmap.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1:], reverse=True))
   ```

   outputs

   ```py
   {
       5: (70, 90, 160),
       4: (60, 90, 150),
       6: (70, 80, 150),
       3: (80, 50, 130),
       1: (80, 40, 120),
       2: (60, 20, 80)
   }
   ```

2. Manually specify the condition inside the lambda by building the tuple **with a minus sign before the value of the key** (`x[0]` in this case):

   ```py
   dict(sorted(hmap.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1][0], -x[0]), reverse=True))
   ```

   outputs

   ```py
   {
       1: (80, 40, 120),
       3: (80, 50, 130),
       5: (70, 90, 160),
       6: (70, 80, 150),
       2: (60, 20, 80),
       4: (60, 90, 150)
   }
   ```

Comment: @HariharanRagothaman BTW, there is a discrepancy in the second part of your question. First you ask about the first element in the tuple but later you ask about the second element

Comment: I want to understand how to sort by the first / second / third element in the tuple. In the other scenario, I wanted to know how to still sort by key, if there was a tie. You answered both precisely. Thanks again.